# getting lazy intialization exception when using toString method

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, proxy, orm

trying to make a small implementation of twitter with hibernate
and i have added features like adding comments,following etc....

there is an account entity which has a one to many relationship with the tweet entity
now after adding a tweet from a certain account, i want show that tweet alongside the account info,
now for that i am trying to use toString(), which throws the following exception

failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: entities.Account.accountTwit, could not initialize proxy - no Session

now i know a little about sessions and proxy in hibernate but don't know how to solve the no session problem in the toString()

here is the account entity

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity

public class Account {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long accountId;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "twitAccount")
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Twit> accountTwit=new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="account_followers",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="accountId")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="followerId")})
    private Set<Account> account_followers=new HashSet<>();


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "account_followers",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Account> followers=new ArrayList<>();


    @ManyToMany
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="account_following",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="accountId")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "followingId")})
    private Set<Account> account_following=new HashSet<>();


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "account_following")
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Account> following=new ArrayList<>();


    public void addFollower(Account acc){
        account_followers.add(acc);
        followers.add(acc);
    }

    public void addFollowing(Account acc){
        account_following.add(acc);
        following.add(acc);
    }


    public void removeFollower(Account acc){
        followers.remove(acc);
        account_followers.remove(acc);
    }

    public void removeFollowing(Account acc){
        following.remove(acc);
        account_following.remove(acc);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account{" +
                "accountId=" + accountId +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", accountTwit=" + accountTwit +
                ", followers=" + followers +
                ", account_following=" + account_following +
                ", following=" + following +
                '}';
    }
}
```

twit entity

````
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@ToString
public class Twit {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long twitId;

    @Column(length = 280)
    private String text;
    private int likes;

    @ManyToOne
    private Account twitAccount;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "commentTwit")
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Comment> twitComment=new HashSet<>();


}```
````

Comment: Provide stacktrace and code where the error occurs.

Comment: the error happens when i try to call the to string method of the account entity


                        `List<Account>twitList=accountServices.getTwitList(account.getAccountId());
                        for (Account a : twitList) {System.out.println(a); }`


and the stack trace refers to the line which i call the toString  ::failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: entities.Account.accountTwit, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments; code and stack traces are unreadable in comments.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you are calling toString outside a transaction.
You can do :

- use fetchType EAGER in your OneToMany and ManyToMany fields or
- remove those collections from the toString method or
- load the collections inside a transaction by calling the function size(). For example getAccountTwit().size().